# Excel VBA Errors Depending on How Column is Filtered

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have a handy function that's called from cell C1 that populates the cell with the filters that have been applied to Column C using the filters dropdown: `=ShowColumnFilter(C:C)`
As soon as the user clicks OK in the dropdown, the cell displays the filter(s).

However, when I apply a filter to that same column using VBA below from a command button or hyperlink, the column is correctly filtered but the Function ShowColumnFilter returns an error.

```
'Code Snippet:
With ActiveSheet.Range("A:W")

    .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Some Criteria Here"

End With
```

```
Function ShowColumnFilter(rng as Range)   

'Only the relevant code included here. Works fine when filtering through dropdown, but gives error after applying filter through the VBA in Worksheet_FollowHyperlink.

     Dim sh As Worksheet
     Dim frng As Range
     
     Set sh = rng.Parent

     Debug.Print sh.FilterMode          
     'When filtered from UI dropdown OR after executing VBA Code Snippet from Worksheet_FollowHyperlink returns TRUE

     Debug.Print sh.AutoFilter.FilterMode         
     'When filtered from UI dropdown returns TRUE but after executing VBA from hyperlink or command button creates an error: "Object variable or With block variable not set"
    
    Set frng = sh.AutoFilter.Range       'Errors only after  filtering by executing VBA from separate routine
    ...
End Function
```

This one has me perplexed because the function ShowColumnFilter is populating a cell and is not invoked directly by another sub. I'm trying to populate C1 with the filtering that has been applied to the column regardless of how the user filtered it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Full code here:

```
Function ShowColumnFilter(rng As Range)
On Error GoTo myErr
'> PURPOSE: Show filters used in a specific column _
   USAGE:   =ShowColumnFilter(C:C)
   
    Dim filt As Filter
    Dim sCrit1 As String
    Dim sCrit2 As String
    Dim sOp As String
    Dim lngOp As Long
    Dim lngOff As Long
    Dim frng As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
 
    Set sh = rng.Parent
    
    If sh.FilterMode = False Then
        ShowColumnFilter = "No Active Filter"
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    '**** Included only for debugging *****
    Debug.Print sh.FilterMode
    Debug.Print sh.AutoFilter.FilterMode
    '**************************************
    
    Set frng = sh.AutoFilter.Range
 
    If Intersect(rng.EntireColumn, frng) Is Nothing Then
        ShowColumnFilter = CVErr(xlErrRef)
    Else
        lngOff = rng.Column - frng.Columns(1).Column + 1
        If Not sh.AutoFilter.Filters(lngOff).On Then
            ShowColumnFilter = "No Conditions"
        Else
            Set filt = sh.AutoFilter.Filters(lngOff)
            On Error Resume Next
            lngOp = filt.Operator
            If lngOp = xlFilterValues Then
            
                For i = LBound(filt.Criteria1) To UBound(filt.Criteria1)
                    sCrit1 = sCrit1 & filt.Criteria1(i) & " or "
                Next i
                sCrit1 = Left(sCrit1, Len(sCrit1) - 3)
            Else
            
                sCrit1 = filt.Criteria1
                sCrit2 = filt.Criteria2
                If lngOp = xlAnd Then
                    sOp = " And "
                ElseIf lngOp = xlOr Then
                    sOp = " or "
                Else
                    sOp = ""
                End If
            End If
            ShowColumnFilter = sCrit1 & sOp & sCrit2
        End If
    End If
    
myExit:
    Exit Function
myErr:
    Call ErrorLog(Err.Description, Err.Number, "GlobalCode", "ShowColumnFilter", True)
    Resume myExit
End Function

Sub ErrorLog(strErrDescription As String, lngErrNumber As Long, strSheet As String, strSubName As String, bolShowError As Boolean)
On Error GoTo myErr
'> PURPOSE: Record Errors in an Error Log

    If bolShowError = True Then _
        MsgBox "An error has occured running " & strSubName & " on worksheet " & strSheet & ": " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbInformation, "VBA Error"

myExit:
    Exit Sub
myErr:
    MsgBox "VBA Error - Error Log: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume myExit
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
On Error GoTo myErr
'> PURPOSE: Fires whenever a hyperlink is clicked on Sheet 1

Dim sValue as String

sValue = "Some Useful Criteria"

     '> Select the sheet:
     Sheets("MySheetName").Select
        
     With ActiveSheet.Range("A:W")
                
            If Len(sValue) > 0 Then _
                .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=sValue
            
     End With
        
     '> Go to the top row:
     ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    
myExit:
    Exit Sub
myErr:
    Call ErrorLog(Err.Description, Err.Number, "Sheet1", "FollowHyperlink", True)
    Resume myExit
End Sub
```

Comment: I think I understand, but my confusion is that if you are showing the column filtering in cell C1, but the filtering is applied to ALL rows in columns A:W, then I think the filtering would kind of lose it's mind trying to filter on Column C when the first item (C1) is a function that really doesn't have a static value to filter. If your header row is really in Row 2 (for example), then try setting your filter range more explicitly to avoid including row 1.

Comment: I moved the Function =ShowColumnFilter(C:C) into Cell A1 (to populate A1 instead of C1 with the results from Column C filtering) and the result is the same error. The same error happens if I move the Function into cell Z1 etc.

Comment: But I think you're still having the same problem that now the filter is choking on column A because of the non-static value in A1. Is there a header row? Is there data that should be sorted starting in row 1 and if so, why are you trying to show the filter in the same row as other data?  Can you post 5 rows of sample data to illustrate your situation?

Comment: What is the rest of the `ShowColumnFilter` code? Having trouble reproducing the error. Adding `ShowColumnFilter = frng.Address` for example gives a valid output regardless of how the filter was applied.

Comment: Row 1 is blank except for one cell that contains =ShowColumnFilter(C:C). Row 2 is the header row. Rows 3 and beyong contain the data. =ShowColumnFilter(C:C) works fine when filtering using the dropdown. It just doesn't play well when invoking filtering through VBA. I will post the full ShowColumnFilter code in an edit of this post, although the error happens when setting variables and the rest of the code seems irrelevant.

Comment: Do you have a table (`ListObject`) in the sheet? Or is this just raw data?

Comment: Raw data. Not a table. Also, the code snippet is executed in this case from a Hyperlink NOT a command button using the Worksheet_FollowHyperlink method.

Comment: Using "=ShowColumnFilter(C:C)" in Cell C1 I do not need to refresh the sheet. It automatically executes and populates the cell as soon as the user clicks OK in the filtering dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem you're running into is linked to exactly when your `ShowColumnFilter` function is running. As a UDF, it's executed when the worksheet is recalculated. Applying an `AutoFilter` kicks off a recalculation. So if you catch the call stack in your `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` routine, you can detect that the `ShowColumnFilter` function is entered ***immediately*** following the `.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=sValue` statement. So your function is actually catching the worksheet and the filter in a somewhat unknown state.

I was able to solve this issue by protecting that section of code by disabling events and automatic calculations:

```
Sub ApplyTestFilter()
    'Hyperlink Code Snippet:
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A:W")
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">500"
    End With
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This forces the automatic calculations to delay until you've completed your filtering. (NOTE: in some cases you might have to explicitly force the worksheet to recalculate, though I didn't encounter that situation in my small test.)

Comment: I figured it had to do with some uncomitted state but I had no idea how to handle it. I plugged your code in and it's working. Much thanks. In the actual app I run a loop and concatinate the filtering of all columns in the sheet to get a potentially long string result. Your fix has helped greatly. Thank you!